# ESP 32 does not connect to wifi, AUTH EXPIRE error

Tags: wifi, esp-idf

The wifi scanning happens and the list of all 2.4 GHz ssid's get listed properly. While trying to connect, it reports error, and sends WIFI disconnect.

```
    I (5826) TEST: WIFI EventID : 1  
    I (5826) TEST: ap records found : 1  
    I (5826) TEST: ap_list:  
    I (5826) TEST: ap_list[0].ssid = XXXX2-4  
    I (5826) TEST: cred found : XXXX2-4:xxxxxxxx  
    I (5836) TEST: WIFI_EVENT_SCAN_DONE  
    I (5876) TEST: in NET_DO_CONNECT XXXX2-4:xxxxxxxx  
    I (7906) wifi: new:<6,0>, old:<1,0>, ap:<255,255>, sta:<6,0>, prof:1  
    I (8656) wifi:state: init -> auth (b0)  
    I (9656) wifi:state: auth -> init (200)  
    I (9656) wifi: new:<6,0>, old:<6,0>, ap:<255,255>, sta:<6,0>, prof:1  
    I (9666) TEST: WIFI EventID : 5  
    I (9666) TEST: Disconnect reason : 2
```

The following are connected in my device;
GPIO 26,13,4,25 to mosfet as switch
GPIO 22,21 to I2C
19,23,18,5 to SPI
UART to 15,2; 1,3; 16,17

ESP version:
esp32 d0wdq6-v3

Please help me resolve this issue. I think, I made a reasonable search, and I have tried most solutions provided online, but to no avail.

The esp 32 was supposed to connect to the AP, for which ssid and password is provided in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I've came across the same problem when coding my ESP32 base libraries ( see here : https://github.com/aeonSolutions/aeonlabs-ESP32-C-Base-Firmware-Libraries )

You have to add this code after running `WiFi.softAP` or `WiFi.begin` for the WIFI to work.

```
WiFi.setTxPower(WIFI_POWER_8_5dBm);
```

More information about this can be found here: https://www.wemos.cc/en/latest/tutorials/c3/get_started_with_arduino_c3.html#wifi

I've programmed a small wifi test firmware to find the optimal power output for a given antenna:

```cpp
    #include "WiFi.h"
    const char* ssid     = "TheScientist"; // Change this to your WiFi SSID
    const char* password = "*******"; // Change this to your WiFi password
    long timer=0;
    
    wifi_power_t wifiPWR[11];
    int pos = 0;
    
    void setup(){
        wifiPWR[0]=WIFI_POWER_19_5dBm;
        wifiPWR[1]=WIFI_POWER_19dBm;
        wifiPWR[2]=WIFI_POWER_18_5dBm;
        wifiPWR[3]=WIFI_POWER_17dBm;
        wifiPWR[4]=WIFI_POWER_15dBm;
        wifiPWR[5]=WIFI_POWER_13dBm;
        wifiPWR[6]=WIFI_POWER_11dBm;
        wifiPWR[7]=WIFI_POWER_8_5dBm;
        wifiPWR[8]=WIFI_POWER_7dBm;
        wifiPWR[9]=WIFI_POWER_5dBm;
        wifiPWR[10]=WIFI_POWER_2dBm;
      
        Serial.begin(115200);
    
        // Set WiFi to station mode and disconnect from an AP if it was previously connected.
        WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
        WiFi.disconnect();
        delay(100);
       
        Serial.println("Setup done");
    }
    
    void loop(){
        WIFIscanNetworks();
            // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
    
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("******************************************************");
        Serial.print("Connecting to ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        Serial.println("trying to connect using WIFI power("+String(pos)+") " +String(wifiPWR[pos]) +"db" );
        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
        WiFi.setTxPower(wifiPWR[pos]);
        timer=millis();
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && (millis()-timer) < 15000) {
            
            delay(500);
            Serial.print(".");
        }
        if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
          Serial.println("connected successfully" );
          Serial.println("");
          Serial.println("IP address: ");
          Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        }else{
          Serial.println("failed to connect" );
        }
        pos++;
        if (pos>10)
          pos=0;
        // Wait a bit before scanning again.
        delay(5000);
    }
    
    
    // *********************************************************
    void WIFIscanNetworks(){
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
      WiFi.disconnect();
      delay(100);
      int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
      String dataStr = "";
      if(n == WIFI_SCAN_FAILED){ 
         Serial.println("Wifi Scan Failed");
      }else if (n == 0) {
        Serial.println( "no nearby WIFI networks found\n");
      } else {
        dataStr = "\n=====    " + String(n) + " WiFi networks nearby =============\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
          dataStr += padString( String(i + 1), 3)+ ": ";
          dataStr += padString( String(WiFi.SSID(i)), 33);
          dataStr += " RSSI:" + padString( String(WiFi.RSSI(i)), 4) + "db (";
          dataStr +=  padString( String( RSSIToPercent(WiFi.RSSI(i) ) ), 3) + "%)";
          dataStr += " CH:" +  padString( String(WiFi.channel(i)), 2);
          dataStr += WIFIencryptionType(WiFi.encryptionType(i) == WIFI_AUTH_OPEN) ? " pwd: no\n" : " pwd: yes\n";
        }
        dataStr += "===============================\n";
        Serial.println( dataStr );
      }
      // Delete the scan result to free memory for code below.
      WiFi.scanDelete();
    }
    
    //************************************
    String WIFIencryptionType(int i){
           switch (i){
                case WIFI_AUTH_OPEN:
                    return "open";
                    break;
                case WIFI_AUTH_WEP:
                    return "WEP";
                    break;
                case WIFI_AUTH_WPA_PSK:
                    return "WPA";
                    break;
                case WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK:
                    return "WPA2";
                    break;
                case WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK:
                    return "WPA+WPA2";
                    break;
                case WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_ENTERPRISE:
                    return "WPA2-EAP";
                    break;
                case WIFI_AUTH_WPA3_PSK:
                    return "WPA3";
                    break;
                case WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_WPA3_PSK:
                    return "WPA2+WPA3";
                    break;
                case WIFI_AUTH_WAPI_PSK:
                    return "WAPI";
                    break;
                default:
                    return "unknown";
            }
    }
    /// *************************************
    String padString(String str, int size){
      uint8_t padLen = str.length();
      for(int i=0 ; i< ( size - padLen); i++ ){
        str += " ";
      }
    return str;
    }
    
    //*********************************
    uint8_t RSSIToPercent(long rssi) {
      if (rssi >= -50) {
        return 100;
      }else if (rssi <= -100){
        return 0;
      }else{
         return (rssi + 100) * 2;
      }
      // ▂▄▆█
    }
    // ********************************************************
```